# How do I increment an IntegerField variable in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a small detail, I have a form and in one of its fields I want to get a number (example 1) and fill out the form. I want to add another product and to increase and exit the consecutive number (that would be 2) and so on successively.

When I run the python manage.py migrate it marks an error in my model.py and I do not know how to fix it.

I want it to come out increased by 1 in the textbox automatically when I upload a new product but I do not know how to do it, can you help me please?

**Model.py**

```
class Equipo(models.Model):
    folio  = models.IntegerField()
    marca  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    modelo  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    serie  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    express = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    numem = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    responsable = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    departamento = models.ForeignKey(Departamento)
    puesto = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    estado = models.ForeignKey(Estado)
    estatus = models.ForeignKey(Estatus)
    hdd = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    procesador = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ram = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ubicacion = models.ForeignKey(Ubicacion)
    fechaal = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    ultman = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    proxman = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    status  = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.folio)

    def number():
        folio = Equipo.objects.count() #Here I frame error when I do the migration
        if folio == None:
            return 1
        else:
            return no + 1

    incremcode = models.IntegerField(_('Code'), max_length=5, unique=True, \
    default=number)
```

**view.py**

```
def altaeq_view(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = EquipoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('#')
    else:
        form = EquipoForm()
        return render_to_response('altaeq.html',{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**form.py**

```
class EquipoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Equipo
        fields = ('folio','marca','modelo','serie','express','numem','responsable','departamento','puesto','descripcion','estado','estatus','hdd','procesador','ram','ubicacion','fechaal','ultman','proxman','status',)
        labels = {
            'folio':('Folio'),
            'marca':('Marca'),
            'modelo':('Modelo'),
            'serie':('Serie'),
            'express':('Express Service Code'),
            'numem':('Numero de Empleado'),
            'responsable':('Responsable'),
            'departamento':('Departamento'),
            'puesto':('Puesto'),
            'descripcion':('Descripcion'),
            'estado':('Estado'),
            'estatus':('Status'),
            'hdd':('Disco Duro'),
            'procesador':('Procesador'),
            'ram':('Memoria Ram'),
            'ubicacion':('Ubicacion'),
            'fechaal':('Fecha de la Alta del Equipo'),
            'ultman':('Ultima Fecha del Mantenimiento'),
            'proxman':('Proxima Facha del Mantenimiento'),
            'status':('Siempre debe de Estar Marcado'),

        }

    def clean_folio(self):
        folio = self.cleaned_data['folio']
        try:
            ee = Equipo.objects.get(folio=folio)
        except Equipo.DoesNotExist:
            return folio
        raise forms.ValidationError('Este Numero de Folio ya Existe')
```

Comment: By the way I'm using the version of django 1.8.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run migrations, the model classes aren't directly available. That's because your database and the class might differ (until the migration is ran...).

You can replace your method like this:

```
def number(self):
    return self.objects.count() + 1
```

---

Note:
If `if folio == None` is not necessary. That cannot happen, `count()` will return an integer. Also in Python, you can write this: `if folio is None`.

Comment: 'class Equipo(models.Model):
 folio  = models.IntegerField(default=lambda:Equipo.objects.latest('id').folio + 1)'